# Replace special character in data frame

Tags: r

I have a dataframe which contains in different cells a special character which I know which is. An example of the structure:

```
df = data.frame(col_1 = c("21 myspec^ch2 12",NA), 
                col_2 = c("1 myspec^ch2 4","4 myspec^ch2 212"))
```

The character is this  `myspec^ch2` and I would like to replace with -. An example of expected output:

```
df = data.frame(col_1 = c("21-12",NA), 
                col_2 = c("1-4","4-212"))
```

I tried this but it is not working:

```
df [ df == " myspec^ch2 " ] <- "-"
```

Comment: You might want to look into `gsub()`

Comment: @tobiasegli_te  this `gsub(" myspec^ch2 ", "-", df)` because it is not successful

Comment: Try `gsub(" myspec^ch2 ", "-", df$col_1, fixed = T)`. Also, look for a tutorial how to index and manipulate data.frames, that's very basic and a good point to start.

Comment: `apply(df, 2, function(x) gsub(" myspec\\^ch2 ", "-", x))`

Comment: @tobiasegli_te thank you I will try but it is for the whole dataframe and not only for one column

Comment: Use `apply` as @PoGibas says and `fixed = TRUE` as @tobiasegli_te says, and you'll be there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get `gsub` work on whole dataframe use `apply`:

```
apply(df, 2, function(x) gsub(" myspec\\^ch2 ", "-", x))
```

Comment: Can also use `fixed = TRUE` instead of escaping the special character.

Comment: Thanks. It works. Just a question in order to understand what 2 means?

Comment: Happy to help! `apply` with `1` iterates over rows and `apply` with `2` iterates over the columns.

Answer (score 1):

You really want to do a regex-style substitution here. However, in regex, `^` is seen as the beginning of the line (rather than a literal caret). So you can do something like this (using the stringr package):

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

fixed_df  <- df %>%
    mutate_all(funs(str_replace_all( . , " myspec\\^ch2 ", "-"))
```

Note the double backslashes in front of the caret--that escapes the caret and tells R to interpret it literally, rather than as the beginning of the line.